# Suddenly "Dummy output" and no sound

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I have followed most post here with similar title/apparent issues, no options helped. First, my situation:

- I have a fresh install of 20.04, everything is working fine for more than a week
- Today I used my laptop (Dell Inspiron, audio is an Intel card) and I let it unattended (on my desk) too long so it went to sleep mode.
- I can't seem to be able to bring it back, so I pressed the power button to force shutdown then rebooted
- After that sound didn't work, only visible output is a "Dummy output"

I have tried with no success:

- editing the few things in `alsa-base.conf` and `blacklist` (rebooted, `force-reload` ... )
- checked my kernel driver where properly loaded in `modprobe`, that the file existed
- re-installed all already installed `*pulseaudio*`, `*alsa*`, `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic` (my kernel version is 5.4.0-42)
- IMPORTANT note: I have booted on the USB 20.04 liveCD and I have sound, which means the hardware is not broken

I have ran the `alsa-info` which generated a lots of info. At quick browsing of it, nothing seems wrong, all hardware input/output seems there. I will continue checking it, I can upload if that helps.

Comment: I would avoid using the power button to force shutdown (weren't you able to login to a text terminal? or just issue SysRq keys to the kernel directly ignoring your *sleeping* desktop?)  On power outage (or forced power as you describe), I always boot a *live* system and `fsck` (file system check) my partitions; that may fix your issue (if it's corruption caused by loss of power).

Comment: When the laptop goes to sleep, there is nothing I can do: screen is off, keyboard doesn't seem to respond (apart from the power button). I wish I could fix it. Not sure it's because of swap space too small or large, or some settings I need to do to enable waking-up properly...

Comment: I would try Ctrl+Alt+F4 to switch to terminal, SysRq keys vary on command, but Alt-SysRq+REISUB (ie. hit & hold ALT then hit SysRq followed by commands REISUB where you type each letter whilst holding reboot; the B at the end tells machine to reboot)...   Even if GUI/desktop is stuck/frozen, SysRq keys are executed by kernel so if kernel is running it'll respond (even if nothing appears on screen which isn't a clue as to OS, just the GUI/desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a last post I didn't really believed because there wasn't any explanation, but it solved my problem.
I did `sudo apt purge timidity-daemon` then rebooted. Sound was back.
To proof it further, I re-installed it. Poof! Sound gone.
So for me, the solution was to:

- `sudo apt purge timidity-daemon`
- either reboot or `sudo alsa force-reload`

It seems timidity is installed by default, so I guess something got broken when I force shutdown and this package got exclusivity or some sort on the sound...

Comment: Funny, `alsa force-reload` freezes for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just removed the Timidity package as a whole and rebooted.

```
sudo apt-get remove timidity
```

Other forums seem to indicate that the config file for Timidity has been broken by something preventing the file's read permissions.  Perhaps the updated security features in 20.04 are at issue here.