# Automatic Lock Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: sound, lock

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, locks automatically. And after this sound output switches to dummy output. The sound setting gets normalized after restart only. And all the processes taking place terminates.
Help me with this. Due to this issue video call gets disconnected in between only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persistent Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output)

Comment: Check your `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` and then see this recent answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218413/output-device-is-dummy-output and/or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266611/suddenly-dummy-output-and-no-sound

Comment: After unlocking screen, open terminal and try `pulseaudio -k`. Does this restore the sound?

Comment: @PabloBianchi I think this one is different because the dummy output goes away after a reboot and only shows up after locking and unlocking.

Comment: Could you add the output of `journalctl -p warning | grep pulseaudio` when this happens?

Comment: Why it turns off automatically in the first place?